# HDAjackRetask: tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/reconfig: No such device

Tags: audio, alsa, microphone, deepin

I am trying to reconfigure the setup of my microphone with HDAjackRetask however when I click reply I get the message:

> tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/reconfig: No such device

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I am running Deepin 15.1 desktop. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow hdajackretask [source](https://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-tools.git;a=blob;f=hdajackretask/apply-changes.c;hb=refs/tags/v1.2.2#l36), you can see it creates nothing else than a script in temp folder and run it with root privileges.
I'd suggest to start from that; `errors.log` may have some additional clue.

And then: does *reconfig* file exist in the first place?
Because it's [not](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/hda/hda_sysfs.c?h=v4.19#n754) even created if kernel hasn't been compiled with CONFIG_SND_HDA_RECONFIG option.

Last if this still hasn't told you nothing, you might consider to [enable](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2151624) [tracepoints](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/notes.rst?h=v4.19#n625). For as much as I can't see a rationale, sending [raw commands](https://web.archive.org/web/20170103014750/http://www.asyndetic.com/2013/04/11/on-debugging-intel-high-definition-audio-in-linux-part-i/) is the last possible thing.

They can be eventually interpreted with hda-decode-verb contained in hda-emu:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/hda-emu.git
autoreconf -i
./configure --with-kerneldir=/path/linux-2.0
make install
```

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/762957/on-reconfiguring-hdajackretask-after-a-clean-install-of-16-04-apply-now-to-tes/1088419#1088419
You should not start `hdajackretask` with `sudo`.